# How to make a polynomial so that f(i) = 1/(2^i)?

Tags: output-formatting, polynomials

I know that, sequence has formula $f(n) = \dfrac{1}{2^n}$ satifying the conditions $f(1)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, $f(2)=\dfrac{1}{4}$, $f(3)=\dfrac{1}{8}$, $f(4)=\dfrac{1}{16}$. Now I am trying to find a polynominal that also satisfies these conditions.

```
f[x_] = a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d;
Solve[{f[1] == 1/2, f[2] == 1/4, f[3] == 1/8, f[4] == 1/16 }, {a, b, 
  c, d}]
```

> {{a -> -(1/96), b -> 1/8, c -> -(53/96), d -> 15/16}}

With more conditions, $f(1)=\dfrac{1}{2}$, $f(2)=\dfrac{1}{4}$, $f(3)=\dfrac{1}{8}$, $f(4)=\dfrac{1}{16}$, $\ldots$,  $f(10)=\dfrac{1}{2^{10}}$. How can I make a polynomial without solving a system of equations?

Comment: I can't correct the typo because an edit must be at least 6 characters.  I think the last expression before ". How can" should begin with f(10), not f(4).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[Table[{i, 2^-i}, {i, 4}], x] // Expand
(*    15/16 - 53 x/96 + x^2/8 - x^3/96    *)

InterpolatingPolynomial[Table[{i, 2^-i}, {i, 10}], x] // Expand
(*    1023/1024 - 254437 x/368640 + 348803 x^2/1474560 -
      2458693 x^3/46448640 + 5561 x^4/655360 - 17653 x^5/17694720 +
      83 x^6/983040 - 43 x^7/8847360 + x^8/5898240 - x^9/371589120    *)
```

The $i$-values of the data points are actually the default assumed values, and so we can code-golf this last example down:

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[2^-Range[10], x] // Expand
(*    1023/1024 - 254437 x/368640 + 348803 x^2/1474560 -
      2458693 x^3/46448640 + 5561 x^4/655360 - 17653 x^5/17694720 +
      83 x^6/983040 - 43 x^7/8847360 + x^8/5898240 - x^9/371589120    *)
```